# How can I solve the Compilation error: syntax error on my VBA sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sub that are calling for execute other two subs in the program, but when I try to execute it pops up the Compilation error: syntax error right on the fisrt line of the sub.

```
Sub MacroPrimaria()

Call SAPOpenSessionFromLogon
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Call executarsap
MsgBox ("PROCESSAMENTO FINALIZADO")
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SAPOpenSessionFromLogon()

Dim SapGui
Dim Applic
Dim connection
Dim session
Dim WSHShell

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", vbNormalFocus

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do Until WSHShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

Loop
Set WSHShell = Nothing
Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Applic = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = Applic.OpenConnection("S/4 HANA - PRODUÇÃO", True)
Set session = connection.Children(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub executarsap()

Dim Application, SapGuiAuto, connection, session, WScrip

'**IMPORTANTE**: Abaixo daqui, basta colar o scrip gerado pela gravação do SAP, sem retirar nada:

'This sub it's okay and has confidential stuff so its just to know.

End Sub
```

I'm gettin stuck with this error on the lines:

```
"Sub MacroPrimaria()"
```

```
"Sub SAPOpenSessionFromLogon()"
```

I'm expecting to get able to execute the macro

Comment: The Call keyword is kind of deprecated. If you use it, try adding a pair of parentheses: `Call SAPOpenSessionFromLogon()`. The recommended way would be just `SAPOpenSessionFromLogon`.

Comment: Try using `Option Explicit` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Comment: @VBasic2008 When I try to add a pair of parentheses on the Call keyword they disappear right after I click on other line or try to execute

Comment: @braX Yes!! they are sorting out the Subs, but are not part of the code

Comment: your code should compile as long as MacroPrimaria() and SAPOpenSessionFromLogon() subs calls are concerned : please be more specific about at what stage you get what error message

Comment: `Dim Application` might cause a problem as it's a VBA keyword.  [Application object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object))

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't giving a compile error for me.

This is the code I use to interact with SAP and it hasn't given me any problems so far (can't remember where I found it on the Internet though).
It may help.

```
Public Sub Execute_SAP()
    
    'Login details here.
    Dim LogInDetail As Variant
    LogInDetail = Array("***YOUR USER NAME***", "***YOUR PASSWORD***")
    
    'Open the SAP Log-In screen and wait for it to load.
    Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", 4
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Do Until WshShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    Set WshShell = Nothing
    
    Dim SAPGui As Object
    Set SAPGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    
    Dim Appl As Object
    Set Appl = SAPGui.GetScriptingEngine
    
    Dim Connection As Object
    Set Connection = Appl.OpenConnection("S/4 HANA - PRODUÇÃO", True)
    
    Dim Session As Object
    Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
    
    With Session
    
        'Log-in to the session.
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "300"
        
        'The next two lines accept the username and password - LogInDetail variant holds those two values.
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = LogInDetail(0)
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = LogInDetail(1)
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "EN"
        .findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        .findById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0 'ENTER
        
        'Rest of SAP code - each line starts with
        ' .findById("wnd[0]
        'Use SAPs macro recorder to get the detail... is probably what you've got in executearsap()
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help!!

Apparently the file that I created the script was corrupted, when I create a new file the code runs properly.